# tcpdf, code does not work after AddPage()

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have this code 
[pdfcode](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/879b6b6d15e8a8bbbae7225135e9feda114bc871)

see line 95
I am trying to get the data from post of a form and create a pdf.
The form is an mobile app form using iformbuilder.
The code does not go any further after the line $php->AddPage()
please advice.

```
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false,false,$response_array);

    $pdf->SetTitle('Cp pdf');
    $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');
    file_put_contents($file, "creating pdf record", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
     // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

    // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

    // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
        $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    }
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 12);
    $pdf->AddPage();
```

Comment: Since your code is long, you should give a relevant snippet of it and the link to the rest of the code.

Comment: I added the relevant snippet. Can you help